# The Undying Deva

Tags: dnd-4e, player-characters, reincarnation

Can a player continually play the same Deva character according to RAW?

The reason I ask is because according to the PHB2, the deva are simply continually reincarnated to a deva shrine or holy place of some kind. Though usually without many of their previous memories, this does not mean the personality is gone.

Comment: It's not really possible to provide a useful answer to this question without some more details of what you have in mind.

Comment: The D&D Novel Spinner of Lies by Bruce Cordell has as a main character a Deva named Damascus. I've not read it so I can't really suggest what you might learn from the book, but it could help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's really more of a fluff thing, so RAW doesn't enter into it.

Personalities *do* remain the same, but having lost the vast majority of his/her memories it's **very** much up for the debate whether s/he is "the same" person.

Additionally, it's not unreasonable for your DM to claim that since the deva lost all his/her memories, s/he is back to being a level 1 character.

Even if your DM does allow you to return with your earned level and all skills/feats, that doesn't really do much to help you rejoin the party. They don't know where you reincarnated, and you don't even know who they are or that you're supposed to be helping them. Also, what happened to all your equipment?

Finally, (unless my memory has betrayed me) nothing in the description indicates how *long* it takes for a deva to reincarnate. It doesn't do you much good to have your character return with all their levels & feats if it takes you a decade to do so: the story's plot is probably not going to just sit on hold while you reincarnate.

TLDR: Only if you convince your DM to handwave away a *lot* of fluff issues.

Comment: For all we know, the OP *is* the DM.

Comment: @starwed: Then the TLDR becomes "only if *you* handwave away a lot of fluff issues."

Comment: Yes, I was suggesting you rewrite your answer.